# Uploading rtf file in php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, undefined, rtf

I can upload other file without error. But whenever I tried to upload rtf file in php it fails. My code it below:

```
if(isset($_POST['pid'])){           
    if($_FILES['uploadname']['name']==''){
     //Failed
    }else{
    //upload the file
    }
}
```

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" accept=".csv,.doc,.pdf,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.rtf,.txt, image/*" 
        name="uploadname" style="width:100%;">
   <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max; ?>">
</form>
```

$max = 62914560 bytes

I got undefined index uploadname

The server log:

> PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 24783980 bytes exceeds the limit
>   of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I upload the same file (resaved as doc format using msword) without problem. But when it comes to rtf it fails. I can upload other files like doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf, txt and all image files without problem.
What could be the problem. I am using php 7.1.19 Thanks

Comment: How exactly does it fail? Any error messages on the screen or in the servers error log? What does your form look like?

Comment: Please also provide the html form you're using to submit the files.

Comment: @Capricorn, I updated my question with the html form. I don't think my question deserves downvote. I also provide the error which is undefined index uploadname.

Comment: Please explain why you downvote? I can improve my question.

Comment: I can't speak for the people who actually downvoted your question, but to me what you're trying to do is a very common task in php. Thus there are a multitude of tutorials online and related questions here on SO, addressing almost all of the issues that may occur. As the guide for asking questions suggests (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) one should do an extensive research before asking a new question. This would have resulted in your problem being solved quicker and not having another question for common problems here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) **must precede the file input** field, and its value is the maximum filesize accepted by PHP. This form element should always be used as it saves users the trouble of waiting for a big file being transferred only to find that it was too large and the transfer failed. Keep in mind: fooling this setting on the browser side is quite easy, so never rely on files with a greater size being blocked by this feature. It is merely a convenience feature for users on the client side of the application.

You put that field **after** the file input, so it will be ignored.

> The PHP settings (on the server side) for maximum-size, however, cannot be fooled.

… and it looks like your server-side configuration is set to a lower value anyway, so you need to increase that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did updated my MAX_FILE_SIZE size. my rtf file is 23MB. I also increase the upload setting in my php.ini But I still get the same error. undefined index

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your HTML form has enctype="multipart/form-data".
2. If your file input tag name is "uploadname".

Comment: Yes it it. I can upload other files like doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf, txt and all image files without problem.